# Defining a JavaScript object that is created with a parameter and has properties and methods

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm struggling with some JavaScript Syntax.

I want to define a new object type that I can re-use.

Instances of the object are to be created with:

```
myInstance = new myObject("documentElementId");
```

When a new Object is created I want to be able to set a few parameters for the object with:

```
myObject.param1 = "value1";
myObject.param2 = "value2";
```

I also want to define some methods for the new object, for example:

```
myObject.show();
```

and

```
myObject.setText("Some text string.");
```

But I am really struggling with the syntax.

```
function myObject(IdOfParentDiv) {
    var DivToBuildIn = document.getElementById(IdOfParentDiv);

    //DivToBuildIn.innerText = "Loading now..."; // This was to test access to the DIV.. this bit works OK.

    function setText(textToSet) {
        DivToBuildIn.innerText = textToSet;
    }
}
```

This is as close as I get, but when I call this as follows, I get reference errors or `myInstance.setText is not a function` errors depending on exactly how I call it, for example:

```
var myInstance = new myObject("myTestDiv"); myInstance.setText("Hello World");
```

Results in `myInstance.setText is not a function`.

I feel like I'm close, but it's obviously not right somewhere.

(Note, I don't want to use `class` as I want compatibility before 2015 browsers)

Comment: Well first of all you'll have to return the function otherwise why would it be accessable for myInstance?
So at the end of `function myObject` you'll have to return something like `return { setText, someProperty: 'foobar',  ... }

Comment: Ah, yes, it must return something to be assigned to `myInstance`... I see that. But how do I return an instance of myObject that can then be worked on as described by setting properties or methods later?

Comment: The posted answer explains some solutions already, check it out =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the method on the `prototype`.

```js
function myObject(IdOfParentDiv) {
  this.DivToBuildIn = document.getElementById(IdOfParentDiv);
}
myObject.prototype.setText = function setText(textToSet) {
  this.DivToBuildIn.innerText = textToSet;
}
var myInstance = new myObject("myTestDiv");
myInstance.setText("Hello World");
```

```html
<div id="myTestDiv"></div>
```

You could also use a `class` with private members for better encapsulation.

```js
class myObject {
  #DivToBuildIn;
  constructor(IdOfParentDiv) {
    this.#DivToBuildIn = document.getElementById(IdOfParentDiv);
  }
  setText(textToSet) {
    this.#DivToBuildIn.innerText = textToSet;
  }
}
var myInstance = new myObject("myTestDiv");
myInstance.setText("Hello World");
```

```html
<div id="myTestDiv"></div>
```

Comment: First example is the one I've gone for as it doesn't use `class` which, at 6 years old, is still a bit new for comfort. Thanks.

Comment: @FatMonk Happy to help.